# Samba with RSAT permission issues

Tags: server, permissions, samba, samba4

So I am trying to set up a PDC using Ubuntu17.04 and Samba4 that I can manage with Windows RSAT, and not need to do anything on the Linux side other than updates to the server and whatnot. The end state is to set this company up with something that they can easily manage without needing to understand Linux, without having to pay for the Microsoft license. Full disclaimer is that I am also a complete and total Linux noob, and only know what I have found on a few forums and from a couple classes in college.

My issue is that everything seems to run just fine except authentication, so if I make the file shares and roaming profile locations 777 then no issues. The second that I try and use any form of security it won't give Windows users access to the files. I'm certain that this has something to do with authentication, most likely winbind (since getent isn't showing any domain groups or users).

Here are the basic config files, let me know what I'm doing wrong please, or if you need any more information.

Also wbinfo -g doesn't output anything. Don't know if that helps, but everywhere I look people are asking for that output, and mine doesn't show anything.

[My smb.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNyKt.png)

[My krb5 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzzff.png)